# Which of my Visual Studio extensions are slowing?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

My Visual Studio 2012 has become slow to open. In 'safe mode' it's fast again. Presumably some extensions are slowing Visual Studio. Which?

Is there an analogue of Internet Explorer's feature which shows load time for each extensions? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2009/07/18/how-to-make-ie-open-new-tabs-faster.aspx

Comment: What about disabling/uninstalling extensions on-by-one and testing Visual Studio performance?

Comment: That would work, but I'd prefer an O(1) solution.

Comment: Try binary search -- disable half of them and try it, then repeat. O(log(N))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start Visual Studio from the command line and specify the `/log` option to have Visual Studio write all details to the `ActivityLog.xml`. It's not a pretty pop-up dialig, but you can get the information you want from there.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241272.aspx

Comment: Thanks yes I see there are 'begin package load' and 'end package load' items for each extension. I'll try to pair them and subtract the timespamps.

Comment: If you could write a nice pup-up message for that, I'd love that ;)>

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Jesse, `ActivityLog.xml` has the information I want. Unfortunately, it's unreadable. I wrote a Python script to extract the relevant details

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
try:
    f = open(sys.argv[1])
except IndexError:
    f = sys.stdin

soup = BeautifulSoup(f)

loads = dict()

for entry in soup.find_all('entry'):
    description = entry.find('description')
    if not (description and "package load" in description.get_text() ):
        continue

    print(entry)
    print()
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved my similar problem with "**The Activity Log Profiler**". It's just an xsl-Stylesheet for the Activity Log and shows the HotSpots and Errors in current ActivityLog.xml

https://github.com/lcorneliussen/ActivityLogProfiler

There is also a Blog-Entry about it:
http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/activity-log-profiler-find-out-which-extension-is-slowing-down-your-visual-studio/